# Web API - Cannot de-serialize request object

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a quick application to try to learn AngularJS with Web API (I have worked with ASP.NET MVC but not had chance to use Web API) server-side, but I cannot seem to get my object to serialize when posting the the Web API method.

My object is a simple User Object which inherits from a BaseEntity object:

```
 public class User : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The name.
    /// </value>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the email.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The email.
    /// </value>
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The password.
    /// </value>
    public string Password { get; set; }

}

public class BaseEntity : MongoRepository.Entity, Interfaces.IEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the id for this object (the primary record for an entity).
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The id for this object (the primary record for an entity).
        /// </value>
        public new int Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="BaseEntity"/> is selected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///   <c>true</c> if selected; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="BaseEntity"/> is deleted.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///   <c>true</c> if deleted; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
```

My latest method attempt is as follows:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(JObject user)
    {
        User userObject = user.ToObject<User>();
        _Repo.Add(userObject);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "User Created");
    }
```

My AngularJS snippet for some clarity on what is being posted from the UI (The properties are set using ng-model and I can see them being passed via Fiddler, even so the Web API method de-serializes these properties to null rather than ""):

```
      $scope.User = {
      Name: '',
      Password: '',
      Email: '',
  }
  $scope.register = function () {
          $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/api/User/',
              data: $scope.User //Also tried JSON.stringify($scope.User)
          })
            .success(function () {
                //Handle successful registration
            })
            .error(function () {
                //Show error message
            });
  }
```

When debugging, I can see the user parameter has been populated with an object. I have tried setting all properties during the request, only one property etc and have called the api via POSTman and the application, which ever way I use, I get a blank User object when I try to parse the user paramter object to my User object. I also get the same when I put the parameter type as my User object.

I have looked around and most examples and answered questions don't inherit from anything, and I have tried different Content-Type's thinking it may be the problem (this was when I had the User object type and the parameter type for the method).

Is there a quirk I am missing with JSON.NET/built in Web API deserialization when it comes to objects derived from other classes, or is there something I am missing?

EDIT: I have removed all inheritance from my object and it binds as I expect, so I am not sure why it doesn't work when there is any kind of inheritance. Is there some setup required to get parameter binding to work when an object inherits from another?:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to work out an answer to my problem, but I'm not sure why I needed to do it when so many example I have seen don't require it! Anyway, I have decorated my User object and BaseEntity with the following attribute:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
```

Could it be that these objects live in their own class library rather than inside the Models folder? I dont know, but either way that seems to fix it and I can then put the User type as my parameter type

Answer (score 1):

I thik WebAPI is clever enough to bind directly to a typed object. So the method can take just a `User` type and not a `JObject`.

Also, make sure the property names in Javascript match exactly to the property names of your model as well. Or else it will hydrate the model passed in with default values, dangerous for booleans!

It could be the routing. Don't forget the default route in WebApi includes '/api/' ("api/{controller}/{id}"), which it doesn't in MVC?

Without a little more detail. This is all I can say.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have tried it with my Web API method parameter as the User object directly at first, but still ended up with the blank object, so changed it to JObject to make sure I was receiving the data as expected. I have modified my original question with the AngularJS scope object I am passing

Comment: If you are using the HTTP service directly, you will need to set the `content-type` header to `application/json`... I would suggest using the `$http.post()` method instead as this sets all the sensible defaults for you. Then you just need to specifiy the URL and data as an js object.

Comment: I have tried with both $http and $http.post with the same result. When checking the call via Fiddler I can see both of them have a content-type of application/json

Comment: I have removed all inheritance from my object and it binds correctly, but its not something I want to do going forward. I have modified my original question with this information, but still require an answer

Comment: Ok... Odd... I have used a class heirarchy before with the serialiser I am sure... Possibly look into the DTO pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). This might be what you require to seperate your application service boundry from your models.

Comment: Not sure why I would need a DTO object to then covert to my object for saving. When I do similar service calls via jQuery to an ASMX service, the System.Web javascript serializer works, as well as just setting the parameter type to the desired object. I don't want to replace the default JSON serializer, but if I exhaust all options (which I nearly have from what I've tried), I'll have to